# Next.js dynamic routing adds to existing path

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

In my Next.js blog with Strapi CMS, I am trying to sort the posts based on its category.
I created a dynamic route for categories [id].js. It is using getStaticPaths like so:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
const categories = await getCategories()
return {
    paths: categories.map((category) => `/categories/${category.id}`) || [],
    fallback: false,
}
```

I am using a dropdown to filter categories.
For example, if I select category 1, the path is like this http://localhost:3000/categories/1.
Till here it's fine.

But the dropdown is still rendered on the page and when I select category 2. Now, the path is http://localhost:3000/categories/categories/2 which of course results in a 404 error.

the expected result is http://localhost:3000/categories/2

The next/link component I am using for dropdown elements looks like so:

```
<Link href="/categories/[id]" as={`/categories/${category.id}`}>
      <a>{category.name}</a>
</Link>
```

I know I did some mistake, but can't figure out what it is.

However, I have a [slug].js for posts, which renders more posts too. That routes to proper posts without adding the extra /posts for the path. But it is not working in a similar way for categories.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

It should return `id` only.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const categories = await getCategories()
  const paths = categories.map((category) => ({
    params: { id: category.id.toString() },
  }))
  return {
      paths,
      fallback: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried this, did not work.

Comment: code updated.. please see if this work.. it worked for me.

Comment: id has to be string => `params: { id: category.id.toString() }`

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. If I type the correct address manually, the required page renders. It's just that extra ` /categories` is added .

btw, tried to convert it to a string. did not work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `parmas` property as in this example? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mean as @Nilesh Patel mentioned? That did not work

Comment: ```export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const categories = await getCategories()
    const posts = await getPostByCategory(params.id)
    const category = posts[0]?.category.name.toString() || ''

    return {
        props: { posts, categories, category },
        revalidate: 1,
    };
}```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right way to solve this, I just added a condition to check if there is already /categories in the pathname. If so, I am not adding /categories to href link like this:

```
    <Link as={this.props.router.pathname.includes("categories") ? `${category.id}` : `categories/${category.id}`}
          href={this.props.router.pathname.includes("categories") ? "[id]" : "categories/[id]"}>
      <a>{category.name}</a>
   </Link>
```

Please let me know if there is any better solution